# Wordpress links/site title won't work

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

I have one Wordpress installation at www.website.com, and a test site at www.website.com/test.

The standard site works fine, but the links on my test site act weird. I use post title as permalink (www.website.com/test/example-post) , and the links look right when I click on them, but they will send me to the standard site (in root folder). So if I have a page with the same title there, I will end up there. If the standard site doesn't have that page title, I will get a 404 there.

Also, the site title won't work, only the post titles (like, the browser title would be *_*_ :blog entry name).

I tried changing htaccess to the folder name of the test site (/test), but that screwed up the standard site (links there took me to the test site, which is not 'open' yet).

Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm new to the site, so I didn't know. I posted my question there as well, hopefully a mod will remove this one if it's not allowed in here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix your permalink structure.

1. Download a copy of your WP database from your live site by going to: `tools > export`.
2. Open the file in a text editor. Find all instances of your current site url's and replace it with your test sites url. **Only the URL, not pages**. *From:  `www.website.com` to `www.website.com/test.`
   Also look for `WP admin` related pages. You might have to do a bit of trial and error until your able to completely change all instances of the site url.*
3. Save and upload it to your test server, and you should be good to go.

This works for either way. Moving `WP` form `Development` to `Production` or moving `Production` to `Development`.

**Pro Tip:** You can also do replace with a bit of `SQL`.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://www.newsiteurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using your main site's root URl somewhere else in your test site.

It could be in menu link or you given static URL.

You can change it from replacing "www.website.com" by "www.website.com/test" and "www.website.com/" by "www.website.com/test/" in your database.
Before replacing anything in your database you should be take backup of your database.

Or

Simply try to check your **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** should be right in their field.
It will be accessible from General Settings in Wordpress admin section.